# Microsoft Office Standard 2010 Not activating with KMS Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, microsoft-office-2010, kms

About a month ago I took the 64GB SSD inside of my workstation out and cloned it to a new 128GB SSD which I put back into the workstation (I had like 4 bytes left...). Everything has worked great and I just resized the partition, but Microsoft Office Standard 2010 comes up with an activation wizard every time I try to use it. As of today I have six days to activate it, but while briefly messing around with it I can't get it to activate with the KMS server, heck I'm not sure its even finding it. Since none of the other workstations are showing the activation wizard I can only assume that it had something to do with me swapping the SSDs.

Does any one know of what I should look for or how I can go about fixing this "error"? All of the clients are Windows 7 and the domain controller is Windows Server 2012 which also has the KMS server on it (if I remember correctly, it's been a year since I set it up...). Help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE (1)**

Here's the output of the `slmgr.vbs.` I can't even see Office listed on there. I'm kind of wondering if I can just uninstall it and rerun the GP update script and have it get redeployed?

```
Name: Windows(R) 7, OCUR add-on for Ultimate,HomePremium,Enterprise,Professional,ServerHomePremium,Embedded
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, TIMEBASED_SUB channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_SLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_SLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_MAK channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_MAK channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, OCUR add-on for Ultimate,HomePremium,Enterprise,Professional,ServerHomePremium,Embedded
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
Please use slmgr.vbs /ato to activate and update KMS client information in order
to update values.

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_SLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_SLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_MAK channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, VOLUME_KMS_W7 channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_SLP channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_COA_NSLP channel
Partial Product Key: #####
License Status: Licensed

Name: Windows(R) 7, Professional edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, RETAIL channel
This license is not in use.
License Status: Unlicensed
```

**UPDATE (2)**

Here's the output of the `ospp.vbs` script.

```
SKU ID: 9da2a678-fb6b-4e67-ab84-60dd6a9c819a
LICENSE NAME: Office 14, OfficeStandard-KMS_Client edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 14, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---OOT_GRACE---
ERROR CODE: 0x4004F00D
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the application
is running within the valid out of tolerance grace period.
Last 5 characters of installed product key: #####
REMAINING GRACE: 6 days  (8534 minute(s) before expiring)
```

Comment: The output of `cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli all` would probably be useful.

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of `slmgr.vbs`.

Comment: run this command instead: **cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus** (http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2010/08/11/how-to-check-the-activation-type-and-status-of-office-2010-installations.aspx)

Comment: I've update the question again with the output of `ospp.vbs`